# What's causing this high SO2 concentrations in Kazakhstan?

Tags: air-pollution

I was using this website for weather conditions around the world called Ventusky (https://www.ventusky.com/) and one of its features allows you to view SO<sub>2</sub> concentration. I stumbled upon this high concentration of SO<sub>2</sub> near Zhezkazgan in Kazakhstan (https://www.ventusky.com/?p=47.47;65.97;6&l=so2). I googled it but couldn't find anything. Satellite images show desert and mountains. Any ideas what could this be?

Images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The source of SO<sub>2</sub> is the smelter associated with the [Jezkazgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jezkazgan) (Zhezkazgan, Жезказган) [copper mine](https://www.australianmining.com.au/features/the-possibilities-of-applying-the-technology-of-ore-caving-in-caved-in-deposits/), mined by [Kaz Minerals](http://russiamining.com/mining-company-directory/KAZminerals). The [complex](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bozshakol+Copper+Mine/@51.8448413,74.2762165,3921m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x4257527d1c508407:0xcead45e101ef71b1!2sKaz+Minerals+Bozshakol+Copper+mine!8m2!3d51.8103229!4d74.2907172!3m4!1s0x42574db94835460d:0xee5b22335ffe85b1!8m2!3d51.8469867!4d74.291372) also [produces sulfuric acid](http://www.sulphuric-acid.com/sulphuric-acid-on-the-web/Acid%20Plants/JSC%20Kazakhmys%20-%20Zhezkazgan.htm).

If you check for the other atmospheric pollutants with ventusky.com, you will see associated particulate matter - PM 2.5 and PM 10.

Comment: If one had a satellite 70 years ago,  a similar SO2 plume could have been seen at Sudbury Ontario , at the nickel smelters.